# jQuery Validate submitHandler not working with WP AJAX / wp_localize_script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-validate

I am implementing front end login form in wp. And validate form with jquery validate. Using submit handler to submit the form. Validations working good and also ajax, But the main issue is `wp_localize_script` variables not working in submit handler.

Here's my js code:

```
var $form = $(this);
jQuery('form#login').validate({
    rules:{
        username: { required: true },
        password: { required: true }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_login_object.ajaxurl,
            data: { 
                // contains all required values for login
            },
            success: function(data){
              document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;
            }
        });
        $form.submit();
    }
});
```

Here's my wp code:

```
function ajax_login_init(){
    wp_enqueue_script('script' );
    wp_enqueue_script('js-validate' );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_login_object', array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'redirecturl' => get_site_url().'/page'
    ));
}
```

Here I am not getting the `ajax_login_object` values. Suggest me where I am wrong to implement this.

Comment: You would not call `.submit()` after `.ajax()`... that makes no sense.  `.ajax()` submits the form without refreshing the page.  `.submit()` is the default form submit to the `action` URL along with a page refresh.  If you decide to use the default submit instead of ajax, then it would be `form.submit()`; no dollar sign.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set `$ == jQuery` then stick to it. Plus did you mean to put `$form` as your function parameter or?

Also you're localizing your script on what? Where is the `ajax-script` handle.

Try with

```
function ajax_login_init(){
    wp_enqueue_script('script' );
    wp_enqueue_script('js-validate' );
    wp_localize_script( 'js-validate', 'ajax_login_object', array( 
        'ajaxurl'     => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'redirecturl' => get_site_url().'/page'
    ));
}
```

And see if your localized script is in the DOM (inspect it with Chrome and search for `ajaxurl` and `redirecturl`). JS part:

```
var $form = $(this);
$('form#login').validate({
    rules:{
        username: { required: true },
        password: { required: true }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_login_object.ajaxurl,
            data: { 
                // contains all required values for login
            },
            success: function(data){
                form.submit();
                document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You would not call `.submit()` after `.ajax()`... that makes no sense in this context.  If the OP simply wants a default form submit to the `action` URL, then `form.submit()` will suffice, assuming the `submitHandler` function argument is `form`.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your suggestions.